# What is the relationship between $[\Sigma X, Y]$ and $[X \times I, Y]$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If $X,Y$ are pointed spaces in $\text{hTop}_*$, then what is the relationship between $[\Sigma X, Y]$ and $[X \times I, Y]$, where $\Sigma$ means the reduced suspension and the brackets mean the set of all continuous functions from $()$ to $()$?

Indication suggests that there's a bijection between them but I can't see how this could be since quotient spaces aren't in one-to-one correspondence to the spaces they're derived from.

Comment: Instead of all continuous functions, the brackets denote the set of pointed continuous functions modulo pointed homotopy (i.e. base-point preserving homotopy classes of maps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $X\times I$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$ relative basepoints, $[X\times I, Y] = [X, Y]$. There is a natural map $i : X \to \Sigma X$, given by $x \mapsto [(x, \frac{1}{2})]$, which induces a map $[\Sigma X, Y] \to [X, Y]$ given by precomposition with $i$. However, there is no stronger relation between the two. For example, if $X = S^n$, then $[X\times I, Y] = \pi_n(Y)$ and $[\Sigma X, Y] = \pi_{n+1}(Y)$. In particular, the map $[\Sigma X, Y] \to [X, Y]$ need not be injective nor surjective.

Comment: So say that $\tau : [\Sigma X, Y] \rightarrow [X, \Omega Y]$ is a bijection via $[F] \mapsto [F^{\text{#}}]$.  Then since $F^{\text{#}}: X \rightarrow \Omega Y$ we should have $F : X \times I \rightarrow Y$ but we have $F : \Sigma X \rightarrow Y$.  But since there's no particular relationship between $[X \times I, Y]$ and $[\Sigma X, Y]$ how can this bijecton be justified?

Comment: How can there be an inclusion $i:X \rightarrow \Sigma X$?  If $\Sigma X = X \times I / ( X \times \dot I \cup \{x_0\} \times I)$ then isn't $X$ not a subset of $\Sigma X$ and therefore is not an inclusion?

Comment: @OliverG: I mean the map $X \to X\times I$, $x \mapsto (x, \frac{1}{2})$ composed with the quotient map. As for your first comment, how is $F^{\#}$ defined?

Comment: Why is the map $f:X \rightarrow X \times I$ by $x \mapsto (x, \frac{1}{2})$ defined with $\frac{1}{2}$ particularly?  And what map is $f$ replacing in your answer?

Comment: And $F^{\text{#}}$ is defined by $F^{\text{#}}: X \rightarrow \Omega Y$ as the associate function of $F$, but the trouble lies in the fact that $F$ shouldn't have an associate function since it's a map from $\Sigma X$ to $Y$ and not a map $X \times I$ to $Y$.

Comment: I just want to include $X$ as a slice in the cylinder, but not at the bottom or top as the bottom and top are crushed to points when forming the suspension.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the associate function. Maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: From Rotman's Algebraic Topology with $X,Y,Z$ sets:

If $F : Z \times Y \rightarrow X$ is a function, then its associate is the function $F^\text{#}:Z \rightarrow \text{Hom}(Y,X)$ defined by $F^\text{#}(z)=F_z$ (where $F_z: y \rightarrow F(z,y)$)